# flat trivial vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $E=M\times V$ be a trivial vector bundle over $M$. If $\nabla$ is a flat linear connection on $E$, this implies that $(E,\nabla)$ is isomorphic to $(E,\nabla^{\mathrm{triv}})$??, where $\nabla^{\mathrm{triv}}$ is the trivial connection on $E$. In other words, except by isomorphism, every flat connection on trivial bundles must be trivial?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the trivial connection on $E$"?

Comment: $\nabla^{\mathrm{triv}}_Xs=ds(X)$

Answer (score 1):

No. For any choice of base point $p\in M$, a flat connection determines a [holonomy representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) $\pi_1(M,p) \to \operatorname{GL}(E_p)$ (by parallel translating around closed loops), and equivalent connections determine isomorphic representations. The flat connections associated with global frames have trivial holonomy, any nontrivial representation of $\pi_1$ will correspond to a flat connection that doesn't have a global parallel frame.

Comment: Yes, it's true then that all flat connections are isomorphic. I just realized that I misread your original question, and thought you had asked if all connections are _equal_ to the trivial one, rather than isomorphic. My original counterexample is irrelevant, because it is in fact isomorphic to the trival connection (because it has trivial holonomy). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you know some reference where I can read more about holonomy? I would like get a proof of my question

Answer (score -1):

A flat connection on $E$ is defined by a foliation ${\cal F}$ of dimension $dim(V)$ whose leaves are transverse to the vertical foliation $x\times V$. Let $p:M\times V\rightarrow M$ be the canonical projection and $x_0\in M$. You can define $\Phi:M\times V\rightarrow M\times V$ such that $\Phi(z)=(p(z),u(z))$ where  the intersection of ${\cal F}_z$ and $x_0\times V$ is $(x_0,u(z))$. $\Phi$ defines an isomorphism between the connection defined by $M\times y$ and the connection defined by ${\cal F}$.

Comment: Your map $u$ is not well-defined: Leaves tend to intersect fibers in more than  one point.